# Warning equivalent of #pragma poison

Tags: ios, xcode, preprocessor, crashlytics

I use the [`crash`](http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/92522-is-there-a-quick-way-to-force-a-crash) function for testing Crashlytics integrations, but I obviously never want to ship that code in an app.

It's possible to poison identifiers so that any current or future use causes an error:

```
#pragma GCC poison crash
```

Is there an equivalent `#pragma` directive that emits a warning when an identifier is used? I want to be able to build the codebase while retaining a visible indicator that attention is required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work, now that `_Pragma` is available. Instead of using `#pragma GCC poison`, you can just `#define` the identifier `crash` in a way which will generate a warning using `#pragma GCC warning`:

```
#define DO_PRAGMA(x) _Pragma(#x)
#define WARN(x) DO_PRAGMA(GCC warning #x)
#define crash WARN("crash" used) crash
```

The first two macros just make it less work to escape quotation marks. Note that `crash` expands to itself (as well as the `_Pragma`), which works because the C preprocessor doesn't expand a token inside of its own expansion.

If you change `warning` to `error`, you'll get an error instead. You could easily arrange to change all of those by using some more macros, or you could just use `-Werror`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `#warning`

Usage would be as follows:

```
#warning This is a custom message
```

Comment: That adds a warning to a specific line, but it won't automatically flag all future uses of an identifier, as is the case with `poison`.